# ASP.NET Core MSB327 Warning - Found conflicts between versions of [packages] that cound not be resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

While developing ASP.NET Core REST API server, I got 3 warnings.

[image: error_message]

> Warning   MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of
>   "[Package Name]" that could not be resolved.  These
>   reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is
>   set to detailed. [Project Name] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2052

List of Packages are

- System.Collections.Immutable
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

I set log verbosity to **Diagnostic** and I got [this log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1le3vIYx8tCdd8LwpyZPzH0EqjcrdNhQ5)

Current ASP.NET Core version is "2.0".

It does not affects Build process but when I add *Controller* by using Template Code Generator,

[image: error_message]

How can I solve this?